# Undefined value in forEach loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I have this key in an JavaScript object {}

```
  resolve: function () {

        var result = this.initialValue;

        console.log('initial value:',result);  // 5

        this.functions.forEach(function (element, index) {

            console.log('index:', index, 'result:',result); //index=0, result=undefined :(
            var result = element.func(result);

        });

    }
```

result is defined outside the loop (with a value of Number(5)). But upon the first iteration of the loop, the result variable becomes undefined. Is there something about JS that I don't know?

Is the `var result = element.func(result);` call somehow redefining `result` in a weird way? No, that can't be, because that call comes after the first logging of `result`.

in this case element.func() is simply a variable representing console.log()

so `element.func(result)` should be equivalent to `console.log(result)`, but it's printing out undefined instead of 5.

No idea what's going on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a duplicate variable declaration inside the scope of the function. It's logging that variable before it's even defined.

Try getting rid of the 'var' and log it after you reassign it.

```
resolve: function () {

        var result = this.initialValue;

        console.log('initial value:',result);  // 5

        this.functions.forEach(function (element, index) {


            result = element.func(result);
            console.log('index:', index, 'result:',result);

        });

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

in your `console.log`, `result` refers to the **local** variable `result`, so it is undefined (as you define it on the next line.)

Answer (score 2):

You are re-assigning the `result` variable within the `forEach` loop.

`var result = element.func(result);`

So when the loop continues after the first time `result` will be `element.func(result)` and not `this.initialValue`

Answer (score 2):

I believe that because of the `var result` inside of the `forEach(function())` that `result` is being hoisted up to the console.log

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Removing the `var` from inside the loop will fix the issue.